# Is zero (Integer) treated as blank or empty in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates

I tried integer zero in a input field (IntegerField), however that zero never appears to be show after submit.

This is part of my template:

```
{{user_date_table.june_11}}
{% if not user_date_table.june_11_steps %}
 <form action="/steps_count/index/{{ username }}/table/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}              
  <input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" name="june_11_steps"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
 </form>
{% else %}      
 {{user_date_table.june_11_steps}}
{% endif %}
```

I think that `if not user_date_table.june_11_steps` throws "True", i.e. it is blank if I use zero as input. Is this correct, and can I overcome this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python, all of the following are evaluated as `False`:

```
'', "", 0, [], {}, (), False, None
```

So, `user_date_table.june_11_steps` is 0, then `{% if not user_date_table.june_11_steps %}` will be evaluated `True` and that block will be executed.

UPDATE: For solution,

1. If `user_date_table` do not take place in your context while you display the form, or if it is empty, you can use

   ```
   {% if not user_date_table%}
   ```
2. Pass another value to your template, like `display_result`, and use that to check which fieldset will be displayed.

views.py:

```
if request.POST: #saving the post data
    display_result = True
```

template.html

```
{% if not display_result %}
    <form action="/steps_count/inde...
```

But the first approach is always better.